# My mouse listeners don't seem to be working. Can someone help me? I have to move a ball to where my mouse is clicked and it is not working

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

This is the code but it is not working. I thought i added the right thing but the mouse listener is even responding. Much help is needed.

```
class Mouse implements MouseListener {
    /**
    * Moves the ball to the (x, y) location where the mouse has been clicked
    */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        ball.setX(e.getX());
        ball.setY(e.getY());

        if (e.isMetaDown()) {
            ball.move(getX(), getY());
            repaint();
        }
        if (e.isShiftDown()) {
            ball.setRandomSpeed(20);
            ball.setLocation(Math.random(), Math.random());
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

It is not working as you can see. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Did you register the class as a listener? componenet.addMouseListener(new Mouse())

Comment: You will probably want to post a [mre] program code post in your question so we can run the code and experience the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score -2):

You are working with the **java.awt.event.MouseEvent**, right?

The problem is, that you invoke methods on the `MouseEvent e` that do not work like expected in your case. The Methods `e.isMetaDown()` and `e.isShiftDown()` check weather the Meta modfier or the Shift modifier is down on this event. I think you searches for a method to check if you pressed the left ( `MouseEvent.BUTTON1`) or right mouse button (`MouseEvent.BUTTON3`). You can consult this page:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html

to inform yoursef about the Methods that can be invoked on `MouseEvent`s.

You could try these two small changes. (But this code is not tested!!) If you want  somebody to test the code, then please post a minimal reproducible example as @DontKnowMuchBut Getting Better already mentioned.

```
class Mouse implements MouseListener {
    /**
    * Moves the ball to the (x, y) location where the mouse has been clicked
    */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        ball.setX(e.getX());
        ball.setY(e.getY());

        if (e.getButton().equals(MouseEvent.BUTTON1)) {
            ball.move(getX(), getY());
            repaint();
        }
        if (e.getButton().equals(MouseEvent.BUTTON2)) {
            ball.setRandomSpeed(20);
            ball.setLocation(Math.random(), Math.random());
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpfull.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped!

Comment: (1-) MouseEvent extends InputEvent. The isMetaDown() and isShiftDown() methods are defined in the InputEvent.

Comment: You are totally right @camickr. Seems that I have overlooked this. So I have improved my answer.